# Stackoverflow Careers: Technology Preferences

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs

For my likes and dislikes, while I'm sure what I'm going to put for dislikes for my profile, there are some technologies that I like. However, for some of those technologies, I'm not familiar with them, but I am in the progress of learning them and would love to have the opportunities to improve it further in a job setting (although I'm improving them on my own time when I'm not working on school projects or studying for exams for school). In that case, would you recommend putting them on the technologies that I like, or leave them off to avoid misleading people into believing that I'm fluent in those technologies that I'm beginning to learn? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know of any specific technologies that you don't like, that's great! You don't have to fill out every section. It's just there to express a preference if you know there's something you don't want to work with or use.

For me, I've listed [.net] and [windows-programming] because they are far from my core areas of expertise, and [extreme-programming] because I've had bad enough experiences with it that I don't wish to go for it again, but again, if you've got nothing you would rather avoid, you're probably ahead of me.

**Edit**: looks like in my pre-sleep haze I totally misunderstood your actual question.  I think it would be quite fine for you to include technologies that you find interesting, even if you aren't very familiar with them, in your "likes" section. The Favorites/Likes/Dislikes are used by employers to try to find candidates that would best match their positions, which doesn't necessarily mean that you're going to be proficient in all the technologies used by those positions. Quite often it's enough to simply find someone who is Smart and Eager to Learn.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question, although that's also something to consider. I prefer to fill this section to fully reflect my interests. What I'm talking about is being a novice in some specific technologies that I enjoy, should I fill this out in the technologies to reflect my interests?

Comment: @stanigator; you're right; edited!